# MVC equivalent of @Html.ActionLink through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How do I code the equivalent of an @Html.ActionLink through javascript code i.e. call an MVC action which will then create a new View without coming back to the calling view?

Comment: Do you want to use ajax? How do you want javascript to _call_ an action?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`javascript` is a client side language which doesn't know anything about the server side language you are using. Thus it is normal that there's no equivalent in javascript of the server side helper that generates an url using your server side route definitions.

It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve but if you want to use call some url through javascript you could generate this url using a server side helper:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")';
    // do something with the url client side variable, for example redirect
    window.location.href = url;
</script>
```

If you want to use this url in a separate javascript file where you don't have access to server side helpers you could still, depending on the situation, include this url in some DOM element.

For example:

```
<div id="foo" data-url="@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")">Click me</div>
```

Notice the `data-url` HTML5 attribute that we have embedded into the DOM and used a server side helper to ensure that the generated url will always be correct based on our routing definitions.  Now we could in a separate javascript file unobtrusively subscribe to the click event of this div and retrieve the url:

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    // do something with the url client side variable, for example redirect
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

Other examples obviously include the standard `<a>` and `<form>` elements which should be generated using server side HTML helpers and then all you have to do in your separate javascript file is to fetch their corresponding `href` or `action` attributes to retrieve the actual url and do something with it.

Comment: Thanks. It was the "window.location.href = url;" code that I was looking for

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answer helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Can we pass parameters to specific action '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")' in this chunk of code?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to store the URL in a hidden `<div>` somewhere on your page and call it via Javascript later. It would look like this:

**Index.cshtml**:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="url">
   @Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")
</div>
```

Then you can use this in your **Script.js** file to build any links you want.

```
var url = $("#url").text();
```

The URL variable would then contain a websafe link to `/SomeController/SomeAction`.